# Angularjs directive: isolated scope and contained elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Why not the contained/child elements not render when use isolated scope. Suspecting the parent is not rendered yet, I tried adding a $timeout, still no luck. if I remove isolated scope by commenting out

```
 scope: {},
```

it works. What to do make it work, where I need isolated scope and render contained elements.

### Code: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZEwj9z?p=preview

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('Directives', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.data = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}];
});


app.directive('test', function ($timeout) {
  return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {}, //if it is commented out, li would render
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
                console.log('Inside link..');
            }
    };
});
```

template

```
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <ul test>
        <li ng-repeat="d in data"> {{d}} </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think because you want to create a new scope for the directive, you need to pass the model to create a two-way binding:

```
<ul test="data">
    <li ng-repeat="d in data"> {{d}} </li>
</ul>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('test', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {data:"=test"},
        replace:false,
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
            console.log('Inside link..'+scope.data);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An isolate scope does not prototypically inherit from the parent scope; there is no property `data` within your test directive.

To access it you should either directly reference it from the parent:

```
<li ng-repeat="d in $parent.data"> {{d}} </li>
```

or set up two-way data binding:

```
<ul test="data">

scope: {data: '=test'}
```